# Applications of the Hahn-Banach Theorems

Tags: soft-question, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, applications

**Question:**  What are some interesting or useful applications of the Hahn-Banach theorem(s)?

**Motivation:** Most of the time, I dislike most of Analysis.  During a final examination, a question sparked my interest in the Hahn-Banach theorem(s).  One of my favorite things to do is to write a math blog (mlog?) post about various topics so that I can better understand them, but I know very little about Hahn-Banach and a quick google search didn't seem to point to anything neat.  I was interested in seeing what you all liked (if anything!) about the Hahn-Banach Theorems.

Also, I can't seem to make this a community wiki, but I think it ought to be one.  If someone could either fix this, I would appreciate it!  (If not, please delete this!)

Comment: A related question on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26568/why-is-the-hahn-banach-thorem-so-important-closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One I know of is the hyperplane separation theorem for convex sets.  Another is the existence of Banach generalized limits.

Comment: Some details on proof of the existence and some properties of Banach limits using Hahn-Banach Theorem are given in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/80571/

Answer (score 8):

How about the Wiener Tauberian theorem:

**Theorem (N. Wiener 1932).** For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, let $X= \operatorname{span}\{f_t:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (that is the linear subspace spanned by the translates of $f$). Then the closure of $X$ in $L^1$ is $L^1$ if and only if the Fourier transform of $f$ has no zero.

Which, in itself, has applications in many different fields running from number theory to PDE.

Comment: Nice! Can I have a reference to this result ?

Comment: @user50618 It is a famous result, you will find it up in Katznelson's book "An introduction to Harmonic Analysis" or Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: @user50618 You have some references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_tauberian_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

What i know about Hann Banach Theorem is the existence of enough functionals of a dual space on a given space, and these functionals sepearate points of the space. The sufficiency of these functional guaranteed enough maps in a dual space to work with.