# Can I define a bounded sequence whose Banach limit is not unique?

Tags: functional-analysis, constructive-mathematics

[Banach limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit), as a non-constructive object, is not unique. The Banach limit for some sequences, say, convergent sequences, sequences satisfying $a_n = a_{n+m}$ for all $n$ and some $m$, the Banach limit is uniquely determined, but there also exists some bounded sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ whose Banach limit is not unique. Can we formally construct such a sequence, say, $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$, with a explict function $f$, but its Banach limit is not unique for all Banach limit?

Comment: Something like $a_n = \sin(\log(n))$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your inspiring comment, sir. Could you please give some hints on how to show this? Does $\sin n$ also work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a result (IIRC due to Lorenz) which says that for a given sequence $x$ the [Banach limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) can obtain all values between $m(x)$ and $M(x)$ where
$$
\begin{gather*}
M(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \limsup T_n(x),\\
m(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \liminf T_n(x),
\end{gather*}
$$
where $T_n(x)$ is the sequence $\left(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}+\dots+x_{k+n-1}}n\right)_{k=1}^\infty$.

So it suffices to find a sequence such that $m(x)<M(x)$. For this it suffices to take a sequence of zeroes and ones where there are long enough blocks of 0's and long enough blocks of 1's.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80564/show-that-liminf-n-to-inftyx-n-le-alphax-le-limsup-n-to-inftyx-n-f/80571#80571).

You can also find some more information if you look for [almost convergent sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) - they are precisely the sequences for which the Banach limit is uniquely determined. (So your question can be reformulated as looking for an example of a sequence which is not almost convergent.)

Comment: Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 3):

No, $\sin n$ does not work.  You can use the Lorenz criterion (see Martin's answer).  In fact, if $a_n = \sin \log n$ were almost convergent (to value $L$), then in particular
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin \log k = L
$$
But
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin \log k - \frac{1}{n}\int_1^{n+1}\sin\log x\;dx
$$
goes to zero, so we may show the limit with integrals does not exist.
This is easy:
$$
\int\sin\log x\;dx = \frac{x\sin\log x - x \cos\log x}{2} +C
$$
and we get
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\; \frac{1}{n}\int_1^{n+1}\sin\log x\;dx  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\\
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\; \frac{1}{n}\int_1^{n+1}\sin\log x\;dx = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$